Import numpy and scipy to Matlab
Introduction.
I have the following Python function, which is saved as "anderson_darling.py":
def ADtest(a,b):
    rng = np.random.default_rng()
    method = stats.PermutationMethod(n_resamples=9999, random_state=rng)
    res = stats.anderson_ksamp([a,b], method=method)
    print(a)
    print(b)
    print(res.statistic)
    print(res.critical_values)
    print(res.pvalue)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    import numpy as np
    from scipy import stats
    input_list1 = list(map(int, sys.argv[1].strip('[]').split(',')))
    input_list2 = list(map(int, sys.argv[2].strip('[]').split(',')))
    a = np.array(input_list1)
    b = np.array(input_list2)
    ADtest(a,b)

To run this file, I open a Terminal (throgh Visual Studio Code, but this is not relevant), and I give the following command:
(base) xyz@xyz myfolder % python3 anderson_darling.py "[1,3,5,6,4,6,7,1,2,7]" "[1,3,5,6,4,6,7,1,2,7]"

The result, that appears on the Terminal is the following:
[1 3 5 6 4 6 7 1 2 7]                        % <-- array a
[1 3 5 6 4 6 7 1 2 7]                        % <-- array b
-1.4363560826434034                          % <-- res.statistic
[0.325 1.226 1.961 2.718 3.752 4.592 6.546]  % <-- res.critical_values
1.0                                          % <-- res.pvalue

My goal is to make this Python file/function work on Matlab, and I type the following commands on the Matlab's editor:
% Matlab arrays
a = [1,3,5,6,4,6,7,1,2,7];
b = [1,3,5,6,4,6,7,1,2,7];
% Convert MATLAB arrays to Python lists
py_a = py.list(a);
py_b = py.list(b);
% Call the python function "ADtest" within the "anderson_darling" function
py.anderson_darling.ADtest(py_a,py_b)

However, I get the following error on the Matlab Command Window:
Error using anderson_darling>ADtest
Python Error: NameError: name 'np' is not defined

How can I import "numpy" and "scipy" into the Matlab system?
Please consider that I have installed Anaconda, and my installed versions of Python, Conda and Matlab are the following ones.
From terminal:
% python3 --version
Python 3.12.4

% where python3
/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3

 % conda --version
conda 24.7.1

% conda info --envs                                         
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /opt/anaconda3
                         /usr/local/anaconda3

From the Matlab's Command Window:
% Python Version for your system (inside Matlab)
% https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pyenv.html
>> pyenv

ans = 

  PythonEnvironment with properties:

          Version: "3.9"
       Executable: "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3"
          Library: "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/libpython3.9.dylib"
             Home: "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9"
           Status: Loaded
    ExecutionMode: InProcess
        ProcessID: "4128"
      ProcessName: "MATLAB"
  
% Matlab version
>> version

ans =

    '23.2.0.2515942 (R2023b) Update 7'


It looks like you need to configure MATLAB to use the right version of Python. It is probably using the system version, it definitely is not using the Conda one. Use pyenv to point MATLAB to the Python version you want to use.

When you put import in __main__ they will be executed only if the module (file) is run as a script. Move import to the very top of your module, they will be imported and then defined.

Thanks @CrisLuengo, but I do not know how to make that configuration... :-)

Thanks a lot @jlandercy :-) ...Do you mean in this way?
def ADtest(a,b): import sys import numpy as np from scipy import stats.... I mean, toadd the import just under the def ADtest(a,b):? If Yes, well.... I get the same error...

By following the @CrisLuengo comment, it might be that a possible solution could be that one presented by Julian Hapke, in the thread called "MATLAB Crashes when Using Conda Environment Other than Base", in the Matlab Ask Forum (https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/443558-matlab-crashes-when-using-conda-environment-other-than-base#answer_366131). However, that solution is for WIndows machines, while I am using a Mac machine. And I am not able to make the correct modifications :-( Anyone who could help in this situation? :-)

@BostonPlummer All you need to do is read the documentation for pyenv. Your Conda Python executable is /opt/anaconda3/bin/python3. So point MATLAB to that with pyenv('Version','/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3').

But do note that Python 3.12 is currently not officially supported in any MATLAB version. It will likely still work, give it a try, but if it doesn’t you might need to downgrade your Python installation. https://www.mathworks.com/support/requirements/python-compatibility.html
